# A problem of metrization

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $f:X \to Y$ continuous surjective map.

I need prove that $Y$ is metrizable.

Can I prove that $Y$ is Hausdorff?

Because if $Y$ is Hausdorff, i can prove $Y$ is metrizable by a Willard's theorem.

I tried to prove that $f$ is closed to use another result and have that $Y$ is Hausdorff, but I think that is not true.

What could I use it to see that Y is metrizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false. Let $X$ be any compact metric space with at least two elements (say $X=[0,1]$), let $Y$ be $X$ endowed with the trivial topology, and let $f$ be the identity map. Then $f$ is a continuous surjection, but $Y$ is not Hausdorff and thus not metrizable.

Comment: Ok, now i understand. Thank you

Comment: @JesusCarreño The standard meaning of the trivial topology on a set is the topology in which only the empty set and the set itself are open. This is also sometimes called the indiscrete topology. What you have described is usually called the discrete topology, which is Hausdorff (and metrizable).

Comment: Yes, excuse me but i was thinking un the discrete topology

Answer (score 0):

$Y$ is metrisable iff it is Hausdorff.

Left to right is trivial, and right to left follows because $Y$ has a countable network hence countable base ( by compact Hausdorffness) and Urysohn does the rest, as $Y$ is regular (also from compact plus Hausdorff).

$Y$ can easily be non-Hausdorff as we can use the identity map from $[0,1]$ to itself where the image as the cofinite or indiscrete topology, say.